# How to initialize Google Maps in the body tag?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am implementing Google Maps in one of my pages. I know I need to add `onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"` within the `<body>` tag but I am not sure how.

Currently within my page I have pasted the following:

```
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
  <p>To Add your Google Map you must first plot your address by searching</p>
  <p>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="" placeholder="Search For Your Address">
    <input type="button" value="Plot Your Address" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </p>
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 770px; height: 270px; border: 5px solid #EDEDED">
  </div>
</body>
```

Even though this actually works, it must be terrible mark-up as it is a body section within a body section for the main page.

I am using Wordpress but I'm not sure if the above markup is OK or whether I should be putting it in the main page body tag. The problem is that I am not sure how to do this if needed. As I only need it on one page and not my entire site, I don't want to add this to the site's body tag to initialize Google Maps on every page and slow the site down.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you don't want to be adding another body tag into the specific page template that uses the map. Your opening `<body>` tag will be in `header.php` , you should get the page ID of the specific page which you want to load it on and do;

```
<body <?php if (is_page(374)) { echo 'onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"'; } ?>>
```

in `header.php`

Which will add that code to (in my instance) page 374.

To find the page id, just hover over it in the Pages section in the backend and you can see the ID in the link url.

For multiple pages you would use;

```
<body <?php if (is_page(array(374,375))) { echo 'onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"'; } ?>>
```

and you can also use the slug or title instead of ID, but of course they are easy for your client to change and stop that code working.  Here's the codex link on is_page;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page

Comment: awesome, cheers for that. If I needed to have let's say page 374 and 375 would I just separate them by a comma? `(is_page(374, 375))`

Comment: oh an actually just checked my body tag already has a class in it. I guess what you wrote above will just come after it `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

Comment: Yes, that is correct - I've also updated the answer for multiple pages

Comment: No worries at all, glad to help you!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the back and forth but I just put this code into my header.php and when I load up the page in question, nothing loads at all. This is the code I inserted `<body <?php body_class(); ?> <?php if (is_page(array(1974,1685)) { echo 'onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()"'; } ?>>` any ideas what might be wrong in it?

Comment: Well check your source to ensure the markup is there as expected in the body tag.  If it is then something else is the issue. Is the code for the initialize function available, have you loaded the google maps JS in the head etc.  When you say 'nothing loads' are you saying there's a white screen of death (ie code error) or just no map?

Comment: it's the white screen of death i am afraid..I have checked in Firebug and nothing is loading at all, so the source is empty. I see a 500 error in the console, but that's it.

Comment: it must be something to do with the multiple pages array. I reverted to your first code snippet and that worked. Any ideas on the multiple pages?

Comment: I just tested the multiple pages array there on my site and it's working OK. I've just spotted it - I have missed a closing bracket - sorry mate. Have updated the answer, my apologies.

Comment: Brilliant, I can;t tell you the amount of times those brackets got me in the past :) cheers again!